# TableView cells Image have images without images

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm downloading the data from firebase and I managed to put the images to right cells but I get the images with **getData** and it requires file path for images and some of them does not have images on the  stated path but some how I have images on every cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tabelview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableCell
    cell.commentButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.nameLabel.text = annoucements[indexPath.row].Name
    cell.announcementLabel.text = annoucements[indexPath.row].Announcement
    cell.annoucementTitleLabel.text = annoucements[indexPath.row].AnnoucementTitle
    cell.dateLabel.text = annoucements[indexPath.row].Date
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let islandRef = storageRef.child("Announcement").child("\(annoucements[indexPath.row].key!).jpg")

    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: annoucements[indexPath.row].key! as AnyObject) as? UIImage{
        cell.someImage.image = cachedImage
        return cell
    }
    islandRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        } else {
            print(2)
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async { // Adds the images to cache
                if let downloadedImage = image {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: annoucements[indexPath.row].key! as AnyObject)
                    cell.someImage.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }

            cell.someImage.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where do your path references come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tableView.dequeueReusableCell, you actually reuse previously stored cell with its data,

You have to clear the cell of its content by calling prepareForReuse in your TableCell:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    someImage.image = nil // or some placeholder image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In tableview cell are reused so you don't need to surprise why you are getting image on cell even though no image at specific path . 
If you can observe 
 when you call `getData` method from the cell which have no image i think the case where you are getting `error` nothing is set neither in `cell.someImage`  nor in `imageCache`

My suggestion is to if you are going to show temporary image in your cell in case no image available then you should also set that placeholder image on cache when error block executed on `getData` method so it won't execute again and again.  and you can set nil  in  `override prepareForReuse` of your custom cell so you won't get any repeating image.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

This how I accomplished that. Note the `else` statement with a placeholder image:

```
 let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellID")
    if let pic = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].photo  {
        cell.imageView?.image = pic
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
    } else if let imgURL = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].filepath {
        Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imgURL).getData(maxSize: INT64_MAX, completion: { (data, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error downloading: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            // render
            let img = UIImage.init(data: data!)
            // store to datasource
            PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].photo = img
            // display  img
            if cell == tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageView?.image = img
                    cell.setNeedsLayout()
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        // TODO: TODO: Change Image to a proper placeholder
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Angels@2x.png")
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```